# Highlight user.name in git log

Tags: git, shell

I want to be able to highlight with color all strings that match current `user.name` in `git log` output.
For example I use the following command:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad %Cgreen %d %Creset | %s [%an]" --graph --date=local
```

where I highlight ref names with green color.

I want to do the similar thing but for the current username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad %Cgreen %d %Creset | %s [%an]" --graph --date=local | UNAME=$(git config user.name) grep --color -E "$UNAME|\$"
```

Comment: Thank you! But why just dont use `grep --color -E "$(git config user.name)"`?

Comment: That would filter out every commit's but yours. It seems that you just wanted to highlight your name.